# Finding vertex of ellipse given its non-trivial equation

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization, conic-sections

When doing homework for convex optimization I got stuck in the middle of my work with this problem: I need to find the vertices of this ellipse to continue:
$$25x^2+48xy+25y^2=1225$$

Does anyone know how to find them? Thx a lot

Comment: A web search for “equations of ellipse” takes me to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Canonical_form), which has everything you’d need to know to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the change of variables: $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$. The equation of the ellipse is then
$$
{25\over2}(u^2+v^2)+12(u^2-v^2)=1225,
\quad\hbox{that is}\quad
49u^2+v^2=2450,
$$
whose vertices are readily found at $u=\pm\sqrt{2450/49}=\pm\sqrt{50}$ and $v=\pm\sqrt{2450}=\pm7\sqrt{50}$. Change back to $x$, $y$ and you're done.